# Mongo Query Collection for String in Array and Push to New Array Nested Object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

First and foremost it's been a long time since I've done development, let alone anything with Mongo but I've yet to find a solution to what's likely a simple issue.

In context, I'm trying to get an ID on a nested object for future use. The customer collection looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("1223334abc"),
  "mainNumber": "123",
  "notificationAccount" : [
      "channel": "Apple",
       "notificationAccountId": "700002",
        ]
}
```

I have an array with `mainNumbers` and trying to push into an empty array all the accounts that match. So right now it looks like:

```
mainNumbers =  ["123", "234", "345", etc]

accountIds = [];
for(mainNumber of mainNumbers){
 customerProfile = db.getCollection("customers").find({mainNumber})
 if (customerProfile != null {
  customerProfile.map(function(singleCustomerProfile){
   accountIds.push(singleCustomerProfile.notificationAccount.notificationAccountId);
   print('${mainNumber} ${singleCustomerProfile.notificationAccount.notificationAccountId}');
   });

 } else }
    print(''${mainNumber} was not found.);
    
    } 
}
```

This will print out all the `mainNumbers` without Id. So I pulled out the print line so:

```
customerProfile.map(function(singleCustomerProfile){
 accountIds.push(singleCustomerProfile.notficiationAccount.notificationAccountId);
});
 print('${mainNumber} - ${accountIds}')
```

No errors but I'm just getting the `mainNumber` over and over.

I feel like:

1. I'm missing something simple against the `notificationAccount` and my attempts are proving fruitless
2. There is probably a better/cleaner way to get do output of the array on querying.

Any assistance welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, need to wait until the data has come. Also, you can simplify the request by using one `find` query by using the `$in` method since you have an array and wanna get the all matched documents by this array. Also, returning the `notificationAccount` field would be good as done below since need only one specific field to use here.

After the response is returned, map the response and store the notification IDs in a variable.
 I guess, the `notificationAccount` field is an **object** so, I mapped it like that. However, if it's an array, then need to get the first element's `notificationAccountId` in the map function.

```js
mainNumbers =  ["123", "234", "345", etc];

const notificationAccounts = await db.getCollection("customers").find(
       { mainNumber: { $in: mainNumbers }}, 
       {"notificationAccount":1, "_id": 0}
);

const accountIds = notificationAccounts.map(({ notificationAccount }) => notificationAccount.notificationAccountId);
```

I also created a test demo, you can test it easily here: 
[Demo Link](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/328rl8RTDr1)

Hope it's clear and useful